# Add data to API results

Tags: javascript, json, database, node.js, api

I'm using an API which returns an array of results, let's call them **"employees"** and let's say it returns **"employee.id"** and **"employee.name"**.

I know the "age" of each employee and I have it in a list (JSON file).

What I'm trying to achieve is: whenever a user makes a search, the app will pull results from "employees", match all the id's from "employees" to id's in my JSON file, and returns an array with **"employee.id"**, **"employee.name"** and **"employee.age"**.

Or at least that's the theory.

What is the best practice? Should the app search the API and then my JSON or both at the same time? How do I "match" the two?

I don't think the language really matters here, but I'm writing it in Node.js

Comment: You can use `async` library to search in parallel

Answer (score 0):

Because you've provided no specifics about the API or JSON file, an answer can't be made very specific either so here's a general concept.

1. Use an async file access method in node.js, read the JSON file into memory and when it loads, parse it into a Javascript array.
2. As soon as you start the async file read, then start your API call.
3. When both async operations have finished (I personally would use Bluebird in nodejs to promisify both operations so they each returned a promise and would then use `Promise.all()` to know when both async operations were done.
4. Then, get the `employee.id` from the API call and do a search for that id in the array of employees that came from the JSON file.  If you only have to do this once, you can do a brute force search through the array (just looping through the array and comparing each object in the array to see if the id matches).
5. Once you find the matching id in the array, you can then get the age and name from that same object and you should now have all the info you want.

---

If this is a common operation, then you probably want to load the JSON file just once, save it persistently in your nodejs application and you may also want to create an index by id so you can just do a direct lookup on the id rather than having to do a brute force search each time.

---

A brute force search of an array of objects for a particular `.id` property could look like this:

```
function findEmployeeById(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < employeeData.length; i++) {
        if (employeeData[i].id === id) {
            return employeeData[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```